# Traces on Hecke algebras and the Jones polynomial

Tags: knot-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, hecke-algebras, jones-polynomial

In his famous paper "Hecke algebra representations of braid groups and link polynomials," (Annals 1987), Jones uses a compatible family of traces $tr_z$ on the [Iwahori-Hecke algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwahori-Hecke_algebra) $H(q,n)$ of type $A_n$ to construct the [HOMFLY-PT polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HOMFLY_polynomial), a polynomial invariant of links. In the paper there are a couple statements that are somewhat mysterious:

> (pg 336): This might also show how to use the other Hecke algebras (not of type $A_n$), and their rich representation theory, in some field related to knots...... (pg 343): Other Hecke algebras exist for other Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams and it would be nice to now if any of the ideas of this paper can be suitably modified for them.

**Question**: Have people gone in this direction? Is there a reference?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer to both questions is positive (since mathematicians tend to leave no stone unturned).   See for example:

Geck, Meinolf; Lambropoulou, Sofia. Markov traces and knot invariants related to Iwahori-Hecke algebras of type B. J. Reine Angew. Math. 482 (1997), 191–213.

What I don't know offhand is whether there is a useful up-to-date survey of the whole subject area, though I know of several surveys of knot theory.

Answer (score 3):

This is a beautiful question that is not trivial at all. After Jones' paper, Lambropoulou constructed a trace on the generalized Hecke algebra of type B, through which, she obtained the analogue of the HOMFLYPT polynomial for knots in the solid torus:
[http://www.math.ntua.gr/~sofia/publications/A4%20cyclotomic-my%20pdf.pdf](http://www.math.ntua.gr/%7Esofia/publications/A4%20cyclotomic-my%20pdf.pdf)

Then, we worked on generalizing this result for knots in Lens spaces Lp,1. Here is a survey on this work:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.06290

Keep in mind that this survey is not updated, since many more results are now known. I am currently writting an updated survey on skein modules via braids and knot algebras, that I hope will appear soon.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Let me know when it appears! (I don't check the arXiv as often as I should these days...)